# How to disable Expect:100-Continue when using WCF in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to get rid of the `Expect: 100-Continue` header in HTTP message, when communicating with WebService using WCF in Windows Store App.
I have found a lot of solutions, but none of them is possible in Windows 8:

1. `ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;` doesn't exist in Store App any more (No `SericePoint` or `ServicePointManager` class),
2. I cannot change configuration in `web.config` file, because it doesn't exist in Store App,
3. It is possible to change the flag in `HttpClient`, but I cannot access it, when using WCF,
4. I tried to manipulate with message headers using `IClientMessageInspector`, but the default HTTP headers are being added later, in higher layers, so my changes will be ovverriden.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: The web.config only exists on asp.net web-applications. In windows applications (and apps) you have the app.config instead, which does exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways to deal with this.

You can turn set expect100Continue="false" in you app.config or web.config, but **this will be global**. This could be an issue if some external services prefer to use the header expect100Continue. Here's how:

```
<system.net>
     <settings>
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>  
     </settings>
</system.net>
```

Or you can do it in code **for a specific endpoint** as follows:

```
System.Net.ServicePoint servicePoint =
     System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(myWcfService.Endpoint.Address.Uri);
servicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
// now execute some service operation
```

Comment: p.s. If your using a web proxy them,                     System.Net.ServicePoint servicePoint = System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(accountFilteringClient.Endpoint.Address.Uri, new WebProxy("http://myproxy.com:8080"));